# 'submerged' in this particular moment

Tags: word-choice, expressions, sentence

How can I say this sentence more properly? Suppose I am with my girlfriend, and I say

> "I want my whole life to be submerged in this particular moment".

I don't think that *submerged* is the right word. What I want to say is that I want my whole life to be in this particular moment that I am with my girlfriend. Can any one construct this sentence so that it sounds pleasant and correct?

Comment: Hello jade, I suggest you to say that sentence with soft music in the background, but you should not be too sincere.

Comment: @Carlo_R. nice one man :)

Comment: I believe the more common phrasing is: *I wish we could stay like this forever.*

Comment: How about "_I'd love to {capture/freeze/fossilize} this moment in amber and wear it on a chain around my neck_"?

Comment: @BillFranke  She might take him up on it: *Werd ich zum Augenblicke sagen: / Verweile doch! du bist so schön! / Dann magst du mich in Fesseln schlagen.*

Comment: @StoneyB: Wonderful lines! Geothe's wonderful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Immersed* is a possibility; *[immerse](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/immerse#Verb)* has sense “To involve deeply [eg] The sculptor immersed himself in anatomic studies”. “I want my whole life to be immersed in this moment.”

Also, *[quintessence](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quintessence#Noun)* (“A thing that is the most perfect example of its type; the most perfect embodiment of something; ... The essence in a thing that is its purest and most concentrated form”) may be relevant, as in 
 “I want this moment to be the quintessence of my life”.   Either of these examples (with immersed or quintessence) sound well enough, but whether they are sensible things to say is another issue.  For one thing, it isn't clear what it means for a life to be immersed, or submerged, or quintessentially found, in a moment.  For another, the subtext to “I want X to be Y” is “but it isn’t Y”.  Perhaps drop the “I want” part.

Comment: why do u think its not sensible to say so?

Comment: @jade, see added sentences in answer.

Comment: u mean "This moment is the quintessence of my life"

Answer (score 1):

The word you're looking for is [subsumed](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/subsume?q=subsume).

Comment: +1, 'subsumed' is a credible word, but 'immersed', suggested by jwpat7, has the right nuance in that romantic context.